# show dynamic array with vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

im newbie with vue so i have a couple of cuestions, im showing a table with some data that i get from a web-service, the thing is , that i dont always get the same amount of data, the data comes in an array, for example like this

```
var todos = [
    {name : "dexter" , color : "orange"},
    {name : "jaime", color : "green" },
    {name : "stack", color : "yellow" },
    {name : "overflow", color : "black" }
]
```

but as i say, I dont alway's get a response with 2 items in it, 
right now i have to declare what item in te array im calling to, and i want to call all the items in the array to show them

```js
var todos = [

  {
    name: "dexter",
    color: "orange"
  },
  {
    name: "jaime",
    color: "green"
  },
  {
    name: "stack",
    color: "yellow"
  },
  {
    name: "overflow",
    color: "black"
  }
]



var i = 0;
var sixthTable = new Vue({

  el: '#sevenTable',
  data: {
    currentPage: 1,
    elementsPerPage: 3,
    ascending: false,
    sortColumn: '',
    rows: [

      {
        name: todos[0].name,
        color: todos[0].color
      },
      {
        name: todos[1].name,
        color: todos[1].color
      },
      {
        name: todos[2].name,
        color: todos[2].color
      },
      {
        name: todos[3].name,
        color: todos[3].color
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    "sortTable": function sortTable(col) {
      if (this.sortColumn === col) {
        this.ascending = !this.ascending;
      } else {
        this.ascending = true;
        this.sortColumn = col;
      }

      var ascending = this.ascending;

      this.rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a[col] > b[col]) {
          return ascending ? 1 : -1
        } else if (a[col] < b[col]) {
          return ascending ? -1 : 1
        }
        return 0;
      })
    },
    "num_pages": function num_pages() {
      return Math.ceil(this.rows.length / this.elementsPerPage);
    },
    "get_rows": function get_rows() {
      var start = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.elementsPerPage;
      var end = start + this.elementsPerPage;
      return this.rows.slice(start, end);
    },
    "change_page": function change_page(page) {
      this.currentPage = page;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    "columns": function columns() {
      if (this.rows.length == 0) {
        return [];
      }
      return Object.keys(this.rows[0])
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 750px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid #44475C;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

table th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  background: #44475C;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  min-width: 30px;
}

table th:hover {
  background: #717699;
}

table td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  border-right: 2px solid #7D82A8;
}

table td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background: #00B4BB;
}

table {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 750px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid #44475C;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

table th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  background: #44475C;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  min-width: 30px;
}

table th:hover {
  background: #007b80;
}

table td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  border-right: 2px solid #7D82A8;
}

table td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background: #D4D8F9;
}

.pagination {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  width: 750px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.arrow_down {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB8AAAAaCAYAAABPY4eKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAvlJREFUSA29Vk1PGlEUHQaiiewslpUJiyYs2yb9AyRuJGm7c0VJoFXSX9A0sSZN04ULF12YEBQDhMCuSZOm1FhTiLY2Rky0QPlQBLRUsICoIN/0PCsGyox26NC3eTNn3r3n3TvnvvsE1PkwGo3yUqkkEQqFgw2Mz7lWqwng7ztN06mxsTEv8U0Aam5u7r5EInkplUol/f391wAJCc7nEAgE9Uwmkzo4OPiJMa1Wq6cFs7Ozt0H6RqlUDmJXfPIx+qrX69Ti4mIyHA5r6Wq1egND+j+IyW6QAUoul18XiUTDNHaSyGazKcZtdgk8wqhUKh9o/OMvsVgsfHJy0iWqVrcQNRUMBnd6enqc9MjISAmRP3e73T9al3XnbWNjIw2+KY1Gc3imsNHR0YV4PP5+d3e32h3K316TySQFoX2WyWR2glzIO5fLTSD6IElLNwbqnFpbWyO/96lCoai0cZjN5kfYQAYi5H34fL6cxWIZbya9iJyAhULBHAqFVlMpfsV/fHxMeb3er+Vy+VUzeduzwWC45XA4dlD/vEXvdDrj8DvURsYEWK3WF4FA4JQP9mg0WrHZbEYmnpa0NxYgPVObm5teiLABdTQT8a6vrwdRWhOcHMzMzCiXlpb2/yV6qDttMpkeshEzRk4Wo/bfoe4X9vb2amzGl+HoXNT29vZqsVi0sK1jJScG+Xx+HGkL4Tew2TPi5zUdQQt9otPpuBk3e0TaHmMDh1zS7/f780S0zX6Yni+NnBj09fUZUfvudDrNZN+GkQbl8Xi8RLRtHzsB9Hr9nfn5+SjSeWUCXC7XPq5kw53wsNogjZNohYXL2EljstvtrAL70/mVaW8Y4OidRO1/gwgbUMvcqGmcDc9aPvD1gnTeQ+0nmaInokRj0nHh+uvIiVOtVvt2a2vLv7Ky0tL3cRTXIcpPAwMDpq6R4/JXE4vFQ5FI5CN+QTaRSFCYc8vLy1l0rge4ARe5kJ/d27kYkLXoy2Jo4C7K8CZOsEBvb+9rlUp1xNXPL7v3IDwxvPD6AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC')
}

.arrow_up {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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')
}

.arrow {
  float: right;
  width: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position-y: bottom;
}

.number {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #00B4BB;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.number:hover,
.number.active {
  background: #ccfdff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="sevenTable">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="col in columns" v-on:click="sortTable(col)">{{col}}
          <div class="arrow" v-if="col == sortColumn" v-bind:class="[ascending ? 'arrow_up' : 'arrow_down']"></div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="row in get_rows()">
        <td v-for="col in columns">{{row[col]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="pagination">
    <div class="number" v-for="i in num_pages()" v-bind:class="[i == currentPage ? 'active' : '']" v-on:click="change_page(i)">{{i}}</div>
  </div>
```

here is my full code i know my array its not actually a web-servce response i put in that way to "simplify" de code

thanks in advice

Comment: So you might get `name`, `color`, and `size` and you would want a table with three columns and those headings?

Comment: You could just declare `rows: todos`.

Comment: right now i have the table with the columns im calling and the headers of the table are taken from the values of the array, but i need to specify how many items of the array want to use, i want to use all items of the array , any tips?

Comment: haha @RoyJ yeah, that work just fine ,do you know how to for example only call `name` ? avoiding `colors`? anyways if you want to post that as an answer so i can vote you as correct !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just assign the web-service-provided data right into your `data` like

```
rows: todos
```